# need two directives per view with 2-way binding to fire watch only once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've written a pagination control directive that is bound to the view controller on `pageNumber` and `pageSize`. When either value updates, the view controller makes the appropriate, paged search and updates the data table. The directive is inserted twice, above and below the data table.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YwaBHpad4mlYyi5RuNGs?p=preview) (you'll want your console open)

The trouble I'm having is that the events fire twice, once for each directive. I tried modifying it to 1-way bind `pageSize` and pass it as an option to `setPage()`, but then the two directives don't stay in sync with each other or the view controller (if it updates pageSize).

Normally, I'd use an isolated scope, but I think that won't work here. Can I make this work like I want?

Comment: Can you move the `$watch` into the parent controller?

Comment: That seems to have worked (Plunker updated), but it's not ideal as it puts the responsibility on all the pages that include the pager to implement the $watch.

Comment: What is the AngularJS mechanic that causes it to execute twice when created in link, but only once in ViewCtrl? I thought it was happening because the top instance called setPage(), and since it updated the pageSize, the bottom instance was updated and also fired its setPage(). How would moving it to ViewCtrl change this?

Or, are two watches created by link? I thought link only ran once?

Comment: You have other page related data in the view controller in your Plunker, so if you're concerned with that, you may want to consider more  than just this `$watch`. Given how you have things architected now, the view controller is the best place for the $watch.

Comment: When you instantiate the directive twice on a page, the link function runs twice (once for each). Your controller is instantiated only once. A main reason for having directives is to give you a nice way to package functionality up and *reuse it* across an app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54297/discussion-between-n13-and-marc-kline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having two directives implement one `$watch` each, move it up in the the parent controller, where it will fire only per value change. Then, if you need to propagate some value to both directives, do that with another isolate scope variable.